# Problems with jQuery logic

Tags: jquery

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/o9kwpwvz/13/)

I want to "copy" HTML structure, change class for one element and "paste" it.

Class is `div-1` (**Line 12 in HTML window**) at first and it should increase with every new append by one number, e.g `div-2`, `div-3` etc. Instead every element is `div-1`.

Don't mind that delete doesn't work properly. I had time to give this Fiddle a little style but no time to make basic functionality working. It's unrelated, doesn't matter.

I made the code as simple as possible, scrap lots of my code and I hope it's easy to read and understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved your issue please try following jquery code :-

I have these line in your code :-

```
$("#all .div-wrap:last-child .div-1").addClass("div-"+newCount).removeClass("div-1");
```

Your modified jQuery code :-

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var prevCount = 0;
    var newCount = 2;
    var newClass = 'div-' + newCount;
    var prevClass = 'div-' + prevCount;

    //This should toggle red sqare color but it doesn't!
      $(document).on('click',' .random-div', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.random-div').toggleClass('green');
      });

    //New cat click
    $('.new-cat').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //"Copy" form
      divGroup = $('.divs').html();
      //"Paste" it below old one
      $('#all').append('<div class="div-wrap">' + divGroup + '</div>');


      NewClass = 'div-' + newCount;
      prevClass = 'div-' + prevCount;

       $("#all .div-wrap:last-child .div-1").addClass(NewClass).removeClass("div-1");

      //Testing   
      console.log('newClass: ' + NewClass);
      console.log('prevClass: ' + prevClass);
      console.log('------------');
      console.log('newCount: ' + newCount);
      console.log('prevCount: ' + prevCount);

      //Change class in order to instansiate Dropzone
      //$(this).closest(prevClass).attr('class', NewClass);


      //Instanciate Dropzone.
      /*
      $('.' + newClass).dropzone() {

        //Not the point of this problem but it works for only 1st appended element because other elements are 
        also named "div-1" <- it should increase with every "get a new one" click "div-2", "div-3" etc.

      }; 
      */




      //Increase counters by 1 in order to give next target 1 number bigger class
      newCount++; 
      prevCount++;

    });




    //Not related stuff, just for functionality but still: take a peek just in case!

    //Delete cat    
    $('.delete-cat').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var countCats = $('.maiden-form').length;
      if ( countCats > 1 ) {
        $(this).closest('.divs').remove();
      }
      else {
        alert('Cmon! Its your last form - dont delete it! And yes, I know how to use upper comma in code, Im just tired after about 5 hours of trying to solve this problem.  I hope you can help me! :)');
      }
     });

});
```

It may help you.

Comment: Is it just me or there's a weird start? It goes from `div-1` to `div-0` and third is without class, then it continues normally.

Comment: Nice! It seems to be working! Can you also find what's wrong on line 45? I've tried to make it work (there's actually like 300 lines of codes I removed), Im tired and can't see the problem.

Comment: This should toggle red sqare color but it doesn't!

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Im not sure if script is not attached or what's the problem..

Comment: can you tell me why you add newClass there?

Comment: I have edited code again, Please try again, Please do vote and male correct answer is its helpful to you.

Comment: I tried to take away all not related stuff to make the code easily understandable. This is necessary in my real code. Is it possible to solve? You've already done enough if that's too big bite.

Comment: Well, toggle is working in my code after fixing `div`. Problem was just in Fiddle with that code. It's actually for other action, I just tried to replicate situation with that box. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes down to your use of the `$(this).closest(prevClass).attr('class', NewClass)` and there are 3 problems:

1. `$(prevClass)` would never work because it needs to be `$('.' + prevClass)`.
2. You're adding new `div-1`s every time you click the button, but this `$(prevClass)` isn't looking for `div-1`, it's looking for `div-2`, `div-3`, etc. So `$(prevClass)` should be `$('.div-1')`.
3. (optional), use jQuery's `.addClass` and `.removeClass` rather than the `attr` property, because the former will preserve other classes you've added to the element.

Here's a properly functioning [jsfiddle for you](http://fiddle.jshell.net/m1ct3cmg/)

As future advice I'd recommend looking at js frameworks like angular so that you're not doing so much difficult low-level DOM operations like add/remove/cloning elements. It gets hairy!

Comment: Thanks! I'll also use your answer to improve my code. It does get hairy but fortunately it's just an exception. I've studied all I know in past year and I don't have time for another framework right now. Maybe in future.